# Java why exception handling needed in lambda when use curly braces

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I have two functions throwing Exception:

```java
public void foo() throws Exception {
  // something
}
public void bar() throws Exception {
  // something
}
```

If I combine those function calls using curly braces in lambda expression, it needs try/catch to handle exception.

```java
public void someFunction() throws Exception {
  someList.forEach(e -> {
    // Show compile error and need try/catch
    foo();
    bar();
  });
}
```

However, if I combine in for-loop, it is fine.

```java
public void someFunction() throws Exception {
  for (SomeElement e : someList) {
    foo();
    bar();
  }
}
```

I though try/catch needed because of new closure created (using bracket), but in for-loop, it does not require.
I solved it by just using for loop, but I wonder why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List#forEach` expects a `Consumer`.

`Consumer` is a (single-abstract-method) interface that looks like this (simplified):

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T>{
    void accept(T t);
}
```

As you see, `accept` does not throw any checked exceptions.

The lambda expression is an implementation of that interface so it cannot throw any exceptions, no matter what the other code does.